# how to jump from the if state without executing else.?

Tags: c

```
for(....)
  if(condition)
    printf(_);
  else
    printf();
```

what code will come here....

Comment: what do you want?? Please properly explain

Comment: In case the if-condition evaluates to true, else is never executed. No need to jump anywhere.

Comment: woud you please add few words to make your question clear.

Comment: The following is off topic.  The semicolon preceding the keyword "else" would not have been included in Algol or Pascal or in about a half a dozen languages that were popular in the 1970s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to jump out of the `if` and the enclosing `for` loop when `condition` is true. You can achieve this using `break`:

```
for(....) {
  if(condition) {
    printf(_);
    break;
  }
  else
    printf();
}
```

Note: I added proper indentation and angle brackets to make the code cleaner.

#### Update after OP's comment

```
int isPrime = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10 && !isPrime; i++) {
  isPrime = (16 / i == i);
}
if (isPrime)
  printf("its a prime no");
else
  printf("not a prime no.");
```

Disclaimer: th condition above is hardly the proper way to detect whether a given number is prime, but still this code snippet illustrates the general idiom of saving the result of an expression from a loop and inspecting it later.

Comment: if 'if condition' becomes false,else part'll be executed,and break is nt used at all. anyway the question is not clear first.

Comment: I'm not even sure if this is what the OP is asking, but if it is then I would avoid the use of `break` and instead consider including `condition` in `for` loop's test: e.g. `for (int i=0; condition && i < 10; i++)`. Using `break` works and is perfectly valid, but it means you have to read through the code to find all the exit conditions of the `for` loop, instead of just looking at the `for` statement itself.

Comment: @GrahamS, same here. Your suggestion is cleaner indeed. I didn't want to start optimizing the solution before ensuring that this is actually what the OP is after.

Comment: @GrahamS: with your approach, you have to put an `if` statement after the `for` loop to work out which part of the exit condition applied and whether to `printf(_)`... :-(.

Comment: @Tony: yeah it is just a general style preference/recommendation. If that is a requirement then I might favour `break` (or use a condition with more than two states) - unfortunately it is difficult to tell what the OP is trying to achieve from his question.

Comment: for(i=0;1<10;i++) {
  if(16/i==i) {
    printf("its a prime no");
   i want print else statement once or if statement....
  }
  else
    printf("not a prime no.");

Comment: @K6t, I updated my answer. Please post your updates as edits to your original post in the future, so that everyone can notice them. That may have saved your post from getting closed.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` code is never executed if `condition` is true:

```
if (condition)        // If this condition evaluates to true
{
    printf("Hello");  // Then this code is executed
}
else
{
    printf("World");  // If it is false then this code is executed.
}
```

Edit: Wrapping it in a for loop makes no difference (unless you mean want to actually exit the for loop as well?)