# how to jump from the if state 5th tiime without printing else.?

Tags: c

int n=16;

for(i=0;1<=n;i++) {
  if(n/i==i) {
    printf("its a prime no");

}
  else
    printf("not a prime no.");

i wanto print one statement niether else statement nor if statement....
but output getting not a prime 3time and prime no one time againg...

help me

Comment: Is this Homework? Please tag as such.

Comment: `n/i==i`, when `n` is 16, will only be true when `i` is 4 (or -4). That has nothing to do with prime numbers. Are you actually trying to find the square root of 16?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to jump from the if state without executing else.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990884/how-to-jump-from-the-if-state-without-executing-else)

Answer (score 1):

A few errors:

`n/i==i` is wrong.

`i` divides `n` (aka `i` is a factor of `n`) if `n % i == 0` (remainder is zero)

```
i=0;1<=n;i++
```

`n/i==i` will cause division by zero because initially `i` is zero,
plus having `1<n` in the `for`, the loop will not terminate. It should be `i<n`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

```
int n = 16;

for(i=2;i<n;i++) 
{ 
   if(n % i == 0) 
   { 
      printf("Not a prime no.");
      break;
   } 
   else
   {
      continue;
   }
}

if (i == n)
{
      printf("A prime no.");
}
```